# How do I enable low disk storage warnings?

Tags: nautilus, disk-usage, storage

I haven't been getting any low disk space warnings even though nautilus tells me I've got little space left (varies between reporting 1.4G free to complaining that it's unable to save a small file because disk space is exhausted)? I want to have it reappear so I can write up a log of the disk space fluctuating wildly between 1.4G to 0 bytes so I can ask questions about that.

Comment: It is fairly unclear what you are asking.  What exactly do you want to accomplish?  What warnings do you refer to?

Comment: Ubuntu used to give me a pop-up with a "only xxx amount of disk space remains". Now it doesn't. How do I get it to give me the warnings again.

Comment: I see what you are meaning: test out my answer and see if it helps...

Answer (score 6):

To *enable* these low disk space  warnings (tested on Trusty Tahr 14.04 and Precise Pangolin 12.04) run the following:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.housekeeping active true
```

Or to *disable* the low disk warnings run the following:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.housekeeping active false
```

If you prefer a gui you can see these same settings with the dconf editor:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

On Trusty you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to access the 'Find' feature and search for 'disk space', on Precise the 'Find' functionality does not work well and you must manually drill through the following:

```
org > gnome > settings-daemon > plugins > housekeeping
```

Here you can not only activate and deactivate the disk warning but you can carefully change many other settings:

[image]

**References:**

- [How To Disable Low Disk Space Warning in Ubuntu 14.10?](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2014/12/disable-low-disk-space-warning-ubuntu-14-10/)
- [Launchpad bug: "Low disk space" warning popping up repeatedly.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/881376)

Comment: Well, I tried using the GUI, the "find" function in the "menu" doesn't seem to exist. Of course there's nothing labelled menu in the first place. Do I have to go Mac to get stuff that actually works?

Comment: I did the terminal thing. No change so far but we'll see. Thanks for  the help.

Comment: @Paul: Press Ctrl+F to access the 'Find' feature of the dconf editor...

Comment: Maybe this isn't working because I have 12.04LTS?

Comment: That is a definite maybe :). I will make a 12.04 VM and test...

Comment: All works on 12.04 but 'Find' is a little broken so I have included the correct path to manually drill down through the menus. Also link for the original 'Dsik Warning' bug on Launchpad. Hope this puts the issue to rest for you :)

Comment: How do I see these paths and Launchpad bug link? Did you save them to a webpage?

Comment: Launchpad link is here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/881376 and the path: simply start with 'org' in the left hand window and click through...

Comment: ON my 20.04, I don't have `housekeeping`. Any idea why ?